mkdocs rendering of Mermaid markdown is very small
I am using mkdocs to render a markdown encoding of a mermaid Entity Relationship Diagram. The resulting figure looks like this

I want to, in any way, make the ER Diagram larger.
I have tried converting the mermaid markdown to an image ( https://github.com/hmajid2301/markdown-mermaid-to-images ) but got a lot of strange javascript errors.
I have tried looking for configs in mkdocs to have a wider screenspace parameter for the graph.
I have tried looking for some way to have a zoom-in box that enloses the graph.
Any strategy/ideas would be appreciated!

my basic strategy became markdown -> image. See https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/discussions/7095
